# After accidentally deleting some files from /etc/ppp Internet not working?

Tags: ppp

I just accidentally deleted some files form /etc/ppp folder. After that internet not working I replace ppp folder from a live ubuntu but its still not working.
I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

Use dpkg to discover what files could be related to this file:

```
dpkg -S "/etc/ppp"
```

It will result:

```
resolvconf, pppconfig, pppoeconf, pptp-linux, ppp: /etc/ppp
```

Now, since you know the packages that uses this filepath. You have to reinstall them from the repository:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall resolvconf pptp-linux pppoeconf pppconfig ppp
```

Hope you fix your problem.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on your answer? What does the command do, where to enter it, why it might solve the OP's problem etc.

Comment: But the thing is due to this problem internet is not working (wired connection is disabled) and sudo apt-get need internet access to install packages I think. what to do is there any other way to recofigure it without internet I have ppp folder from a live ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Not if you have the image file.
In the "/etc/apt/sources.list" file, uncomment a line like this

# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)]/ trusty main restricted

mount the image in the cdrom and execute

   apt-get update

and execute the command sudo apt-get install --reinstall package-name